# laravel version 5.0.27 how to rebuild or regenerate composer.json

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have this laravel version 5.0.27 project, it's a live website. It is working without "composer.json" and "artisan" Is there any method to retrieve or regenerate a valid composer.json for this laravel project? By a valid composer.json, I mean it should contain all the elements or packages already existing in the laravel website also It should allow me to generate composer.lock file. And how to retrieve "artisan"?

So that I can install components easily using composer.

Comment: Why am I getting -1 for this question? You guys don't even have an answer for it and you are giving me -1?? For what?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and to rebuild a key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

on initial build:

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer install
```

Comment: I don't have artisan as well. How to rebuild artisan or reinstall artisan?

Comment: When i tried "composer dump-autoload", i received this error: Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html/projectname/application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
composer init
```

Comment: I already tried it, it creates a basic composer file without any package. Though I didn't try to install new package using it. I need to install this package https://github.com/jrenton/laravel-5-scaffold in website. I also tried using the "require-dev": {
    "jrenton/laravel-5-scaffold": "dev-master"
}
 command mentioned in a new composer file, it removed all the existing package and installed this one :( . I want to keep all the already existing packages and install this one as well.

Comment: I tried it again and it again created a basic files, when i added "require-dev" to download this package. on "composer update", it removed all packages and installed a new package. :( I have updated by original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this commends this is working for me.

**$composer dump-autoload**

**$php artisan key:generate**

if you are getting any error like "Composer could not find a composer.json" then try below commend

**$composer install**

Once it is done, you will be able to access our application. if you want to rebuild your app again, then try below commends

**$composer dump-autoload**

**$php artisan key:generate**